# SQL how to round up to tenth (no decimals)

Tags: sql

In Excel I use the ceiling function to round up to the tenth (or more) of a number, like for example:

38.4 =CEILING(A1,10), becomes 40

21 would become 30 etcetc..

In SQl you have a ceiling function but this only seems to round up decimals. Can I use this function or is there are different function I can use?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: [5s google search](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm)

Answer (score 4):

use ceiling function as below

```
CEILING(38.4/10)*10
```

Comment: liked the approach

Comment: Wait a minute. It works for select CEILING(38.4/10)*10 (becomes 40), but not for select CEILING(21/10)*10 (becomes 20, but I expect/want 30)